# Log out existing user when current user login asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have my mvc web application.

**Example:**

In tab1, I logged in with user1 and doing some operations and in tab2, I am logging in with user2, ask pop up for override, I clicked yes and sucessfully logged in now.

Question is when i goto tab1, if i hit refresh(F5) or save button in the page..
For refresh - it displays as user2 is logged by default as session is unique but what will happen if click save button and i dont want to save user1's data for user2 instead i wanted user1 to be logged out popping up "User2 is active so User1 will logged out"?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this because browser entertain only unique session, if user1 is logged in then its session is created to that particular browser if you logged in with other user in other tab then this session will be created and it will forgot previous session.
Instead you can do this,

```
 if (Session["Username"] == null)
                {

                    return View();
                }
                else
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

By this only one user can loggedin

Comment: even if you try to login with user1 in tab2, session remains same right?

Comment: yeah...thats why dont make user1 to login, if it try to login redirect to home index or whatever is your view,

Comment: if you try to login with user1 in tab2 session will be changed to new user which you logged in with user1 in tab2

Comment: therefore dont let user1 in tab2 make login, in your Login controller (get) post my code so if session is null it will make login otherwise not